# Xiaomi redmibook 15 auto power off automatically after desktop have shown in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, bios

i bought brand new xiaomi redmibook 15 2 days ago [installed a lubuntu 20.04 on it], i have disable secure boot correctly, but strangely after the desktop wallpaper have shown it's immediately power off automatically. what do you think about this kind of strange problem?

Comment: You may want to examine the `/var/log/syslog` file to see if there are any hints. If a machine shuts down without warning it is generally due to excessive heat, a loss of power, or hardware failure. Either way, it’s not something anyone can guess about without a great deal more information 

Comment: hello matigo. does the syslog clear itself when the device auto shutdown? i will provide syslog when this problem occur again. btw i have visited the official service center but the technician say that it was because the bios things, i have no idea about this. what do you think?

Comment: hello again matigo. it's happen again, the auto shutdown happen again. but when i checked the syslog it is just show the log of the new boot, not the previous one. so i have no idea with what happen.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved this problem, i think the problem is on driver (the i915 thing), when i revert my machine back to windows with intel uhd installed, it's perfectly usable. now i use wsl to use ubuntu but i will use native ubuntu os again when the driver support my 11 gen intel driver

Answer (score -1):

i had this issue a few while back and i think i know what causes. For me it wasn't the graphic driver, you could see your system log which was located in

> /var/log/syslog

there i found thermald reports a critical temp reached. it seems to report false reading because the laptop feels cool to the touch even when i put my hand under the heatsink. If you also experience this, you may want to stop or disable thermald service on your system.

> sudo systemctl stop thermald
>
> sudo systemctl disable thermald

if you have a difficulty to maintain your system to stay 'on' to run the mentioned command, you may want to boot your system into a safe-graphics mode aka recovery mode.

Comment: jadi udah work belum gan laptop redmi book 15 nya? saya belum nyoba install ubuntu lagi